# any speech to text conversion libraries or apis in python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on converting speech to text for an application I am working on.

Are there any speech to text conversion open source libraries or apis that i can use?

Looking for answers :)

Comment: searching on google "speech recognition python" gives a lot of links you could have tried, here the link in case you don't know to perform it :)[Google Search("speech recognition python")](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=speech+recognition+google&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=speech+recognition+python&oq=speech+recognition+python&gs_l=serp.3..0l3j0i30.2823.5598.0.5871.15.10.1.2.2.5.366.2799.2-6j4.10.0...0.0.wmo5n8MZ5Gw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d70cb7a1447ca32b&biw=1280&bih=699)

Answer (score 3):

Pocketsphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net has python bindings. For more details see the example

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer

Answer (score 2):

You can try dragonfly -

http://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/

Comment: Hey, dragonfly needs win32 library, is there any alternative for linux?